# access and sql server realtime synchronization

Tags: sql-server, database, ms-access, synchronization, real-time

i have a security application that stores its data in a access database.now i'm required to
make a realtime synchronization (replication) between that access database and a new database in sql server 2005. these two database are the same.
any suggestion?!

---

i don't know how to do it using a windows service or not. i need exact technical answer.

Comment: Have you seen: http://sqlserverpedia.com/blog/sql-server-tutorial/how-can-i-synchronize-data-between-ms-access-and-sql-server-databases/ ?

Comment: @Remou: if you'd put that link in an answer and draw it out a bit, I'd think it would be the best answer (the key is the using a SQL Server linked server to make the Jet/ACE data visible to SQL Server, where you can run a set of Appends/Deletes/Updates to synchronize the Jet/ACE with the SQL Server tables).

Comment: thanks Remou.i check the URL.it is really useful and practical.i did it before.above method is not real time.is there a way to do db synch between access database and sql server 2005 using ACCESS LINKED TABLES?i know it is possible and i made it.i replaced the original tables in access database with some linked tables with the same names.so when the application makes a query against the access database,it actually sees our back end sql server 2005 database.it has only one shortcoming.we have only 1 copy of data that is placed in sql server 2005.i need to be a copy of data in access database.

Answer (score 2):

Mostly, I would suggest you use a windows service to periodically check the MS Access db, and attempt to synchronize it with the Sql database.

This will allow you to remove the Human factor, and have this task run periodically to sync the dbs.

Have a look at

- [Creating a Basic Windows Service in
  C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/WindowsService.aspx)
- [Creating a Windows Service in C#](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/window_service11262005045007AM/window_service.aspx)

Also

- [Connect to Microsoft Access .mdb
  database using C#](http://www.dscripts.net/tutorials/2009/01/20/connect-to-microsoft-access-mdb-database-using-csharp/)
- [Beginners guide to accessing SQL
  Server through C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/sql_in_csharp.aspx)

Comment: yes, windows service is a good idea, but before making a windows service i need to know how to extract newly added rows to tables and send them to sql server database.

Comment: i prepare a tiny c# application. problem is how to transfer only newly added rows from access database to sql server database. (preferably i'm told to not use a custom coded application.)

Answer (score 2):

**SQL server has [built-in replication functionality](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb500346.aspx) that you get for free, so you don't need to worry about copying rows & tracking changes.** There are several types of SQL replication that are used for different situations, such as merge replication, snapshot replication, and transactional replication. This last one, transactional replication sounds like what you want. [Merge replication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151176.aspx) is used when you have users that might disconnect, go away and return later to synchronize (like remote users). [Transactional replication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151176.aspx) is used where the subscribers and publisher are reliably connected. [Snapshot replication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151832.aspx) generates a new snapshot each time synchronization occurs, and doesn't think about changes to the data. Read the MSDN documentation and find which of these types is appropriate for your situation.

Using these replication methods will require that you set up your tables in a SQL server or express instance - you can use that to synchronize with your SQL server and keep everything else Access as the front end. I think you want to follow astander's suggestion and use a windows service to trigger synchronization. However you can set up the Windows Synchronization Manager to automatically try to synchronize at startup, shutdown, when the computer is idle, etc. If you need finer control over triggering the synchronization then perhapse use a Windows app or service as astander suggested.

Comment: i think sql server replication is only between sql server and rdbms like itself or mysql and others,, an not between sql server and access.

Comment: SQL Server 2000 could do heterogeneous replication with Jet 4, but that feature was removed in SQL Server 2005.

Comment: What I am suggesting is Sql server replicating to a local Sql server or express instance, and linking to that instance with Access

Comment: the exact point is how the first sql server can grab new rows from access databases? it should be real time as i told.